# ElasticSearch Mapper Parsing Exception while insertion of data

Tags: python, parsing, elasticsearch, mapping, aws-elasticsearch

https://pastebin.com/Xu9CH4B1

I have shared the above data sample that I am trying to insert in Elasticsearch with the Mapping:

```
elastic_search.indices.put_mapping(
                index=index_name_requester,
                doc_type=doc_type_requester,
                body={
                    "properties": {
                        "source_geocode.coordinates": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        },
                        "destination_geocode.coordinates": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        },
                        "geocodes": {
                            "type": "geo_shape"
                        },
                        "route_box": {
                            "type": "geo_shape"
                        },
                        "start_date_time": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
```

**Elastic Search Version**:
6.3.2

**Expected behaviour**:
Insert Successfully

**Current Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in insertion
  File "/home/shobhit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shobhit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 319, in index
    _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
  File "/home/shobhit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/shobhit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 186, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/home/shobhit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse')
```

But there is a similar data with changed Values which is getting inserted, I have shared a link to the data below:

https://pastebin.com/4cQzQQ0M

Please Help figure whats the issue with the data. Thanks!

Comment: can you share the error you get in the ES server logs?

Comment: Hi Val! Here is the elasticsearch error log in the link. https://pastebin.com/iT2de2rc

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem. It was the problem with the lat-long the format of lat-long was wrong in both the cases but 1 got inserted wrongly and the other 1 could not.

The line mentioned below in the logs mentioned the correct problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal latitude value [144.62810199999998] for source_geocode.coordinates
```

Thanks!!